# I want to create a separate hyperlink for each work in a SharePoint column

Tags: json-formatting

I have a "Single line of text" column, which is used to write ticket numbers from another system, such as 123456. Sometimes more than one number applies to an item.

I have the column formatted with JSON so that it creates a link to the other system and pulls up the related ticket (see JSON code below). However, it doesn't work if the person puts in more than one number like 123456, 245124 since the formatting doesn't create a separate hyperlink for each item. Can anyone tell me how I could change the JSON to create a separate hyperlink for each number?

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "=if(@currentField == '', '', ('http://xxx.yyy.com/zzz=' + @currentField))"
   }
}
```